# Is a $CO_2$ explosively pumped laser possible?

Tags: laser

If an explosive that releases $N_2$ and $CO_2$ is detonated inside a laser cavity, will it generate laser light efficiently?

I read a paper where they made a $60$W CW laser with propane and oxygen that was combusted and passed through a $3$mm supersonic nozzle.
https://sci-hub.se/https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1653911

Could a pulsed laser be made if a solid or liquid explosive is detonated inside the cavity?

Comment: Something like https://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Paper/10.1117/12.204935?SSO=1 - "High-explosive charges were used in the early 1980's at Los Alamos National Laboratory to pump high-energy atomic-iodine lasers. Laser outputs at the kilojoule level were measured in a series of experiments."

Comment: @JonCuster i ask about the expanding explosion products acting as the gain medium, not pumping another laser

Comment: Just determining your parameters. Must the explosive itself be the gain, or are non-explosive dopants allowed? Must it explode, or can it deflagrate?

Comment: @JonCuster It should detonate and dopants are allowed, i am thinking about a laser where a significant part of the chemical energy is turned into molecular vibration, then lased in a very short time.

Comment: Hexanitrobenzene (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexanitrobenzene) is a solid at room temperature but has been used as a gas in chemical lasers. Might work, but I have no desire to test it myself…